# Why does declaring a method before the main method produce error c++

Tags: c++

I have a method called `isEven(int i)`, which just simply returns if the number is even. Then I have the main method to test it. This is what it look like:

```
inline
bool isEven(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0
}

int main() {
    std::cout << isEven(5) << endl;
}
```

This compiles just fine. But if I put the function after the main method:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << isEven(5) << endl;
}

inline
bool isEven(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0
}
```

It gives an error. This isn't a duplicate because other questions asked what is producing an error, and the answers just said because you can't do this, but does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: This is because in `main()` it has not seen a declaration for `isEven(int)` yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a function prototype if you would like to define a function after `main`. i.e. Something like this:

```
bool isEven(int i); // Declare.

int main() {
    std::cout << isEven(5) << endl;
}

bool isEven(int i) { // Define.
    return i % 2 == 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a function before it's been declared.  In your case the declaration and definition are the same.

Answer (score 1):

C++ works by going down the file. IF you have main first before you declared a function it is not going to know where that function is since it never got to it. if you declare a prototype before hand then the compiler will know "oh i need to go here for this" since the prototype was before main.

Ex below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int onePlusTwo(int x, int y);  // this is a prototype makesure to include the semicolon

int main(){

    int x = 5;
    int y = 9;
    cout << onePlusTwo(x , y);
    return 0;
}

int onePlusTwo( intx, int y){

  return (x + y);

}
```